# How do I change the upstream branch on a GitHub fork?

Tags: git, github

I've forked a project on GitHub and have been contributing my changes to the "master" branch, however I'd like to change my GitHub project to synchronise with the new "testing" branch.

How do I make the "Contribute" and "Fetch upstream" buttons on my GitHub fork act in reference to the "testing" branch? I seem to have managed to achieve this locally on my project with a terminal, however these changes don't apply to the GitHub project. I'll gladly provide more information if needed.

[image: "Fetch upstream" describing information about the "master" branch rather than the one I need]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just select the `testing` branch in your fork then fetch it. If you don't want to select the branch every time to update it, you can set the default branch of your fork to `testing`.